# How to get final url with python?

Tags: python

I get a link with requests.get and when I check history it's empty although the link redirects to another address when I open it with my browser. What is the problem?

```
import requests
        r=requests.get('http://dir.iran.ir/home?p_p_id=webdirectorydisplay_WAR_webdirectoryportlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=exclusive&p_p_mode=view&_webdirectorydisplay_WAR_webdirectoryportlet_itemEntryId=14439&_webdirectorydisplay_WAR_webdirectoryportlet_cmd=redirectToLink')
    result=r.history
```

but result equal with empty list
and final link is http://www.dps.ir/

Answer (score 1):

You should check the result of that URL first.

```
>>> r.content
'<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="http://www.dps.ir";</script> '
```

`Requests` library doesn't provide ability to execute Javascript, so that explains why there is no history.

PS: Btw you could give `phantomjs` a shot.

Comment: thanks. what's solution for get url?

Comment: @ali.mn I just updated the answer, it's called headless browser, integrated for python.

Comment: if  the url equal to http://dir.iran.ir/home?p_p_id=webdirectorydisplay_WAR_webdirectoryportlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-2&p_p_col_count=1&_webdirectorydisplay_WAR_webdirectoryportlet_itemEntryId=10892&_webdirectorydisplay_WAR_webdirectoryportlet_cmd=redirectToLink 
r.content  not return that script